# Statistics multiplication rule for $P(A\mid B \cap C)$

Tags: probability, statistics

I understand that $P(A \cap B) = P(B\mid A) P(A)$.
But, how do I build on this to expand this version?

$P(A \mid B \cap C)$.

Someone suggested $P(A \mid B \cap C) = P(A)P(B)P(C\mid B)$?

Comment: $P(A\cap B\cap C)/P(B\cap C)$...

Comment: I would rather go with this suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. And how can I use this to prove or disprove that $P(A\mid B \cap C) = P(A \mid B)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(A|B\cap C)P(B\cap C) = P(A \cap (B \cap C))$ thus $P(A|B \cap C)=\frac{P(A \cap (B \cap C))}{P(B\cap C)}$

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition of conditional probability, or Bayes' Rule:

$\begin{align}
 \mathsf P(G\mid H)
 & = \frac{\mathsf P(G\cap H)}{\mathsf P(H)}
 & = \frac{\mathsf P(G)\,\mathsf P(H\mid G)}{\mathsf P(H)}
\\[2ex]
 \mathsf P(A\mid B\cap C)
 & = \frac{\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C)}{\mathsf P(B\cap C)}
 & = \frac{\mathsf P(A)\,\mathsf P(B\cap C\mid A)}{\mathsf P(B\cap C)}
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac{\mathsf P(A\cap B\mid C)}{\mathsf P(B\mid C)}
 & = \frac{\mathsf P(A\mid C)\,\mathsf P(B\mid A\cap C)}{\mathsf P(B\mid C)}
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac{\mathsf P(A\cap C\mid B)}{\mathsf P(C\mid B)}
 & = \frac{\mathsf P(A\mid B)\,\mathsf P(C\mid A\cap B)}{\mathsf P(C\mid B)}
\end{align}$